# xsane exits with "Invalid argument" while scanning with Brother DCP-J725DW, what does it mean?

Tags: 13.04, scanner, brother, sane

Brother DCP-J725DW scan is not functioning in Ubuntu 13.04.

```
xsane error: Failed to open device 'brother4:bus1;dev2': Invalid argument.
```

Comment: what is the output of: scanimage -L